# Is there a way on the new navigation component on back pressed to restore the state on recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-navigation

What I'm using:

- MVP
- Navigation Component
- Single Activity
- Fragments
- RecyclerView
- Realm

Problem:

I have a MainActivity that hosts all the fragments for the application flow.

There's one fragment that has a recyclerview, the more I scroll the more API requests are made. Whenever I press one item to navigate to a different fragment and press back to return to the list, the list only has a small piece of the previous loaded recyclerview, I want everything.

Is it possible to do this with the navigation component?

Can I prevent onCreateView being called whenever I press back?

I've tried to save the View in a static variable, have a onSaveInstance (but it never gets called)

I'm using navigation this way:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
        Navigation.findNavController(view)
                      .navigate(R.id.action_tripsFragment_to_tripDetailsFragment, bundle);
        }
```

MainFragment:

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trips_fragment, container, false);
        mPresenter = new TripsFragmentPresenterImpl(this);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);


        mAdapter = new PaginationAdapter(getContext());
        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
        mPresenter.setLoadingTripsProgressBar(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new PaginationScrollListener(mLinearLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            protected void loadMoreItems() {
                isLoading = true;
                currentPage += 1;

                loadNextPage();
            }

            @Override
            public int getTotalPageCount() {
                return currentPage;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isLoading() {
                return isLoading;
            }
        });

        loadFirstPage();

        return v;
    }
```

What I expect:

Whenever I press back from TripDetails to Trips I want to get my recyclerview as it was, with the previous loaded items at the correct position.

Current results:

Whenever I press back from TripDetails to Trips the recyclerview cuts the items to only the items that are visible, meaning that we'll lose items previous loaded in previous pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference  I've managed to solve the issue by creating a ModelView to keep the data independent of the lifecycle of the fragment